# UICollectionView reload data causing graphical glitching

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm trying to make a custom color picker. The color at on the left is the selected color and the other colors are other options. However, when I reloadData() one of the cells on the edge of the collectionView will have a previous below this new cell.

I have tried making a custom collectionViewCell and then adding views to a default UICollectionViewCell. 
I have tried to diagnose the issue by applying a shadow affect to the views that is how I know that cells are stacking on each other.
Previously I have coded the collectionView by making prototype cells in storyboard, however for a feature I want and I am unable to do this.

This is the code for the cellForItemAtIndexPath and when the collection view is reloaded.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = self.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "colorCell", for: indexPath)
        var color = UIColor.white
        if colors.count == 0{
            color = UIColor(red: CGFloat(mainManager.colors[indexPath.row][0] ), green: CGFloat(mainManager.colors[indexPath.row][1] ), blue: CGFloat(mainManager.colors[indexPath.row][2] ), alpha: 1.0)
        }
        else{
            color = UIColor(red: CGFloat((colors[indexPath.row][0] ) ), green: CGFloat((colors[indexPath.row][1] ) ), blue: CGFloat((colors[indexPath.row][2] ) ), alpha: 1.0)
        }
        if indexPath.row == 0{
            let cellView = UIView()
            cell.addSubview(cellView)
            cellView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            cellView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
            cellView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
            cellView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.8).isActive = true
            cellView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.8).isActive = true
            cellView.roundEdgesAndShadow()
            cellView.backgroundColor = color
        }
        else{
            let centerView = UIView()
            cell.addSubview(centerView)
            centerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            centerView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
            centerView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
            centerView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.4).isActive = true
            centerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.4).isActive = true
            centerView.roundEdgesAndShadow()
            centerView.backgroundColor = color
        }
        return cell
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if colors.count == 0{
            colors = mainManager.colors.sorted(by: { (a, b) -> Bool in
                if a == mainManager.colors[indexPath.row]{
                    return true
                }
                else{
                    return false
                }
            })
        }
        else{
            colors = mainManager.colors.sorted(by: { (a, b) -> Bool in
                if a == self.colors[indexPath.row] {
                    return true
                }
                else{
                    return false
                }
            })
        }
        self.reloadData()
    }
```

Comment: Never ever add views in `cellForItem`, that is literally one of the worst practices when using `collectionView`. Subclass `UICollectionViewCell` instead and add all the subviews that you need there. Then only `dequeue` the cell in `cellForItem` and pass the data or model that the cell may need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are adding views to the cells on the fly, they are getting added to the same cell multiple times in the case of reuse. In the collection view cell's **prepareForReuse** remove all its subviews.